# Unable to edit a title without opening a fold in Vim

Tags: vim, fold

Let's assume you have a cursor at a closed fold as in the picture.

[alt text http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/175564/foldEdit.png](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/175564/foldEdit.png)

**How can you edit the title of SMALLAPPS without opening the fold in Vim?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to edit the first line of the folded block, or the string that appears when the fold is closed? If it's the former, I don't think you can do it without opening the fold. If it's the latter, then have a look at the [foldtext](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/fold.html#fold-foldtext) option. It can be any expression. This expression is evaluated to create this string.

From the docs:

> 'foldtext' is a string option that
>   specifies an expression.  This
>   expression is evaluated to obtain the
>   text displayed for a closed fold. 
>   Example:
>
> ```
> :set foldtext=v:folddashes.substitute(getline(v:foldstart),'/\\*\\\|\\*/\\\|{{{\\d\\=','','g')
> ```
>
> This shows the first line of the fold,
>   with "/*", "*/" and "{{{" removed.
>   Note the use of backslashes to avoid
>   some characters to be interpreted by
>   the ":set" command.  It's simpler to
>   define a function and call that:
>
> ```
> :set foldtext=MyFoldText()
> :function MyFoldText()
> :  let line = getline(v:foldstart)
> :  let sub = substitute(line, '/\*\|\*/\|{{{\d\=', '', 'g')
> :  return v:folddashes . sub
> :endfunction
> ```

An alternative is using the [marker](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/fold.html#fold-methods) folding method. With it, you can enter any string before the fold marker and it will appear when the fold is closed.

From the docs:

> Markers in the text tell where folds
>   start and end.  This allows you to
>   precisely specify the folds.  This
>   will allow deleting and putting a
>   fold, without the risk of including
>   the wrong lines.  The 'foldtext'
>   option is normally set such that the
>   text before the marker shows up in the
>   folded line. This makes it possible to
>   give a name to the fold.
>
> Markers can have a level included, or
>   can use matching pairs.  Including a
>   level is easier, you don't have to add
>   end markers and avoid problems with
>   non-matching marker pairs.  Example:
>
> ```
> /* global variables {{{1 */
> int varA, varB;
> ```

Comment: so the answer is that you cannot edit characters in the heading without opening the fold.